# How to get count of markers visible on a MKMapView?

Tags: swift, mapkit

I'm using this code:

```
let annotationsInVisibleMapRect = self.mapView.annotations(in: mapView.visibleMapRect)
    let count = annotationsInVisibleMapRect.reduce(0) { (count, object) -> Int in
        if let cluster = object as? MKClusterAnnotation {
            if let view = self.mapView.view(for: cluster), !view.isHidden {
                return count + cluster.memberAnnotations.count
            }
        } else if let annotation = object as? MKCustomAnnotation {
            if let view = self.mapView.view(for: annotation), !view.isHidden {
                return count + 1
            }
        }
    }
```

But this code doesn't work correct. Sometimes I see cluster on the map, but this line

> if let view = self.mapView.view(for: cluster) , !view.isHidden...

is giving **isHidden** equal **true**.
I get wrong count as a result.

Answer (score 1):

```
mapView.annotations.filter({ self.mapView.visibleMapRect.contains(MKMapPoint($0.coordinate)) }).count
```

Tested, worked for me :)

Comment: Your filter doesn't work for me. I added 161 markers to a map. mapView.annotations.count returned 212 count. mapView.annotations.filter({ mapView.visibleMapRect.contains(MKMapPoint($0.coordinate)) }).count returned 193 count. But the real visible counts on the map is 145, 2 clusters (137) and (7) and 1 marker.

Comment: @YuraPetrov you can save your markers and use self.mapView.visibleMapRect.contains(MKMapPoint(marker.coordinate)), i dont have more clean solution to this, sorry :(

Comment: I tried using "contains" method, but it also doesn’t work correct. Marker can to be accommodated in cluster and this cluster can to have other coordinators then marker, for example cluster can to have located to the left, out of visible maprect but marker in visible maprect and a user will see wrong count of markers.
In any case, thanks for your advices.